# How can I complete Desert Snakes?

Tags: forza-horizon-5

I have been trying to complete the challenge in Forza Horizon 5 Rally Adventure, but although the timer starts when I leave Valle de Foráneos, I do not get a waypoint to follow.

[image: Desert snakes]

I have tried driving to Devil's Pass and up the ramp to a cave with a snake painted on the side, but the challenge does not complete.

How can I complete this challenge? What do I need to do to make the waypoint appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to complete this today. I went to the north west exit of Valle de Foráneos, and then changed into a Retro Rally car.

I've included a map with the start point in the circle on the right, and the finish point on the left where the arrow marker is

[image]

Once I'd done that, the waypoint showed up for me and I was able to complete the challenge.